# Proving a limit by definition

Tags: limits, proof-writing

My first post on Stack Exchange, for any rules I misfollowed I beforehand apologize.

How can I :

Determine the domain of the function defined by the formula $$f(x) = x + 4 \cdot \pi \cdot \arctan\left(\sqrt{x-3} / (x^2 + x - 2)\right)$$ and prove by definition that $\lim_{{x \to \infty}} f(x) = 0$. In other words, show that for every $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x > \delta$, we have $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{x-1}$.
To demonstrate the limit, we can use the fact that $\arctan$ is bounded, and the resulting inequality $|f(x)| < \frac{1}{x-1}$ to show that $f(x)$ approaches $0$ as $x$ approaches infinity.

Where I have very little understanding of how to build such proof.

Comment: That should be $\lvert f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$ in the definition. Not sure where you're getting the $\frac{1}{x-1}$ from

Answer (score 0):

The claim is false. Indeed, since $\arctan t>-\frac{\pi}{2}$ for all $t\in\mathbb{R}$, we have that

$$f(x)=x+4\pi\arctan\left(\frac{\sqrt{x-3}}{x^2+x-2}\right)>x-2\pi^2\to\infty$$

as $x\to\infty$, so

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty.$$